# Removing duplicate values of gota series

Tags: go, gota

I have a simple gota series and I want to remove duplicate from it.
how it is possible in go?

```golang
func main() {

    new_series := series.New([]string{"b", "a", "c", "a", "d", "b"}, series.String, "COL.1")
    fmt.Println(new_series)
}
```

[b a c a d b]

expected: [b a c d]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To represent a unique set of elements in `go`, use a `map`.

So to create a unique set of strings from a given list, use something like:

```
func setFromList(list []string) (set []string) {
    ks := make(map[string]bool) // map to keep track of repeats

    for _, e := range list {
        if _, v := ks[e]; !v {
            ks[e] = true
            set = append(set, e)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

and to apply this to an existing `gota.Series`:

```
func uniqueGotaSeries(s series.Series) series.Series {
    return series.New(setFromList(s.Records()), s.Type(), s.Name)
}
```

Working playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/zqQM-0XxLF5

Output:

```
Orig: [b a c a d b]
Unique: [b a c d]
```

Comment: this is working for a list, my problem is about gota series.
is there any way to convert series to list?

./prog.go:27:35: cannot use new_series (type series.Series) as type []string in argument to setFromList

Comment: updated answer to create a unique series from an existing series - and preserve name and type.